# How to deploy app on windowsphone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, xap

I have been running in some problem of deploying my app in my nokia lumia 520 its and windows 8 phone.
I have my application in visual studio express 2012 for windows phone.When i build the project and deploy the .xap file in my mobile using the app deployment tool the app gets installed but doesnt runs properly...it is unable to get the css files and the view files.

But when i deploy it using Visual Studio>>Build>>Deploy method the app gets installed and also runs as expected.The main thing is that it also uses the same .xap file which i used while deploying the app using the app deployment tool

Now i am not able to make out where am i going wrong.

Please help

Comment: Have you tried deploying a simple "hello world" app to your device?

Comment: Hi I have tried deploying the hello world using cordova 2.5 version Now I am using cordova 3.7...the problem is if i deploy it through visual studio 2012 i am able to deploy it on my windows phone without any trouble..the trouble starts when i use the xap file and deploy it using the application deployment.exe

Comment: Is this something to do with `Cordova`?

Comment: Yes i am using cordova 3.7 @Kulasangar